# Passing select datename() result to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure with a `varchar` containing the name of the previous month.

```
exec my_sp @subject='Report for June 2011';
```

Except `June 2011` should be dynamic (dependent upon the month you call the stored procedure), not static. What's the best way to accomplish this?

I can get the previous month in the desired format like so:

```
select datename(month, dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))+' '+datename(year, dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))
```

but I don't know how to pass it to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        Declare @reportText varchar(40);
    Set @reportText =  datename(month, dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))+' '+datename(year, dateadd(month,-1,getdate()))

exec my_sp @reportText;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ReportMonth VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @ReportMonth = 'Report for ' + DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))+' '+DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE()))

EXEC my_sp @subject=@ReportMonth
```